# How do I use Python Image Library to convert a libvirt stream to a different image type?

Tags: python, stream, libvirt

Following the sample code below, works perfectly:

```
​import sys
​import libvirt
​domName = 'TestAppliance'
​conn = None
​try:
​    conn = libvirt.open("qemu:///system")
​except libvirt.libvirtError as e:
​    print(repr(e), file=sys.stderr)
​    exit(1)
​
​dom = None
​try:
​    dom = conn.lookupByName(domName)
​except libvirt.libvirtError as e:
​    print(repr(e), file=sys.stderr)
​    exit(1)
​
​stream = conn.newStream()

​imageType = domain.screenshot(stream,0)

​file = "Screenshot of " + dom.name()
​fileHandler = open(file, ’wb’)
​streamBytes = stream.recv(262120)
​
​while streamBytes != b’’:
​    fileHandler.write(streamBytes)
​    streamBytes = stream.recv(262120)
​fileHandler.close()
​print(’Screenshot saved as type: ’ + imageType)
​stream.finish()
​conn.close()
​exit(0)
```

(from https://libvirt.org/docs/libvirt-appdev-guide-python/en-US/html/ch12s02.html)

However, this produces a .PPM image, which is around 3.5mb in size.

How can I use a python stream to push that PPM image in PIL, so PIL can convert it to a (smaller) .PNG (or other format)?

I know that I can save it, and convert it, but that seems so... backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more research gave me the answer. After opening the connection, and finding your VM, use this to take the screen shot, and save it to PNG:

```
vstream = conn.newStream() 
imageType = dom.screenshot(vstream, 0)
file = dom.UUIDString() + '.png'
bstream = vstream.recv(8192)
pyStream = BytesIO()
while bstream != b'':
    pyStream.write(bstream)
    bstream = vstream.recv(8192)
pyStream.seek(0)
image = Image.open(pyStream)
image.save(file, 'PNG')
pyStream.close()
print('PNG saved from '+str(imageType))
vstream.finish()
```

The size difference is 9.1k (PNG) versus 3.2mb (PPM), so it is worth it!